# Running Pyplot over Putty ssh from windows machine to linux

Tags: linux, ssh, python, putty

I am running python code on a linux machine through a putty ssh from a windows machine.

I need to run the following commands:

```
dataframe.plot()
matplotlib.pylot.savfig("some figure.png")
```

Nothing actually gets displayed, but the python code apparently checks to see that the display variable is set.  Anyhow, the display variable is invalid and has nowhere to go.

I did what I usually do when ssh'ing from a linux box:

```
export DISPLAY=:0.0
```

But then I ran into an issue with the X-server.  So I enabled X11 forwarding through putty.

Then, I ran into the issue that there is no X-server on Windows...

Is there a way I can just bypass this and get the data to save?

(or I guess set up an X-server and redirect the display)
(Have installed Xming, and am running it...but that is as far as I've gotten...I still haven't managed to export the display to the X server...)

Comment: Have you considered running a VNC server on the Linux machine, and a VNC client on the Windows machine? This, http://www.linuxtopia.org/HowToGuides/VNC_setup_Linux_Windows.html is a very nice and complete summary of ll the steps necessary. Remember you can even launch a whole copy of your Linux desktop environment (Gnome, KDE, whatever....)  to be displayed on your Windows pc.

Comment: awesome.  I will set that up.  I just need to graph about 4hrs worth of high performance processing before midnight (when the assignment is due)...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As described by [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4706614/94928) and [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3054314/94928), you can configure pyplot to not try to use the display:

```
import matplotlib
# Force matplotlib to not use any Xwindows backend.
matplotlib.use('Agg')
```

Comment: Got it.  at least that will work for now. Thank you.